# The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error

Tags: administration, roles, user-record

I'm creating a user on a scratch org. When I try to add a role I get the following error.
[image]

Comment: If you wish to use Salesforce's out-of-the-box Roles, you should use a scratch org that contains sample data.  Roles should be pushed into the scratch org in the form of source (aka. metadata) as per [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BvaQAE&title=cratch-orgs-hit-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-add-a-role-to-a-user-record-in-the-newly-created-org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use Salesforce's out-of-the-box Roles, you should use a scratch org that contains sample data. Roles should be pushed into the scratch org in the form of source (aka. metadata) as pointed in the [Known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BvaQAE&title=cratch-orgs-hit-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-add-a-role-to-a-user-record-in-the-newly-created-org)

> Salesforce has historically included some "out-of-the-box" roles in our trial orgs, but they're not technically considered "standard" or
> "default". Therefore, in the new "empty" scratch orgs that we've
> introduced we should be filtering them out.
>
> But we are not filtering properly yet. So they are still in the
> "empty" scratch orgs, but in an unusable state. If the use case
> requires a role, it should be pushed into the scratch org in the form
> of source (aka. metadata).